# How can I hide (and fadeIn) a chosen select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using the Chosen library (http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) as JQuery plugin to enhance select elements.
I need to initially hide (and then fadeIn) the select, but the way below doesn't seem to work.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen/chosen.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <select id="firstChosenSelect" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
      <option value=""></option> 
      <option value="United States">United States</option> 
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
      <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
   </select>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#firstChosenSelect').chosen();
     $('#firstChosenSelect').hide();
   </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Ive you tried to put your code in jquery ready callback function?

Comment: Yes, the select still doesn't hide.

Answer (score 8):

Put the select in span and hide/show the span

**In html**

```
<span id="spanForfirstChosenSelect" >
  <select id="firstChosenSelect" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
      <option value=""></option> 
      <option value="United States">United States</option> 
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
      <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

**In javascript**

```
<scirpt type="text/javascript>    
     document.getElementById('spanForfirstChosenSelect').display = 'none';
</script>
```

**In jQuery**

```
<scirpt type="text/javascript>    
     $('spanForfirstChosenSelect').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea. :)
Didn't work with .display = 'none', but it worked with JQuery's hide:
`$('#spanForfirstChosenSelect').hide();`

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap your select with a div:

```
<div id="wrapper"><select id="firstChosenSelect">...</select></div>
```

Then hide it once *chosen* has been fully instantiated (using `chosen:ready`):

```
$('#firstChosenSelect').chosen();
$('#firstChosenSelect').on("chosen:ready", function(){
      $('#wrapper').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First hide your selectbox with "display: none;" or "visibility: hidden"

```
<select id="firstChosenSelect" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." style="width:350px; display: none;" tabindex="2">
```

Then use the chosen() and fadeIn() functions on the selectbox when the content is loaded. I would use the ondocument ready function of jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){ //run when content is loaded..
    $('#firstChosenSelect').chosen();
    $('#firstChosenSelect').fadeIn(400);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this fades in a select that is not Chosen-styled and shows a Chosen-styled select next to it (without fadeIn).

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of undocumented options and events for [chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) so one must read the source to find them. In this case the problem is we do not know when chosen has finished building the styled select boxes so we need to tap into the custom `liszt:ready` event and use some css opacity.

### css

```
<style>
    #firstChosenSelect,  /* the un-styled select box */
    .chzn-container      /* the styled chosen container that gets created later */
    {
      opacity:0
    }
</style>
```

### javascript

We bind a function to be fired when the event occurs. The function will animate the opacity to 1 over 1000 ms. Then using jquery chaining, simply call `.chosen()` on the element immediately after.

```
<script>
  $('#firstChosenSelect').bind('liszt:ready', function(){
    $('.chzn-container').animate({
      opacity:1
    }, 1000);
  }).chosen(); 
</script>
```

In jQuery v1.7+ we could have also used `.on()`

### [demo](http://jsbin.com/azapap/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

you can realize that chosen plugin create all next to the select tag. So with this should be enough:

```
$('#firstChosenSelect').next().hide();
$('#firstChosenSelect').next().fadeIn();
```

Bye;

Answer (score 0):

For me it was enough just adding width.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function() {
        $(".chosen-select").chosen({width: "100%"});
    });
});
```